# Tombstone values not written in Cassandra

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect

I have a sink connector that is writing a JSON message to a Cassandra table. The Cassandra table has a row with some columns having timestamps values. A new message comes to the sink connector and now the timestamps are null. The sink connector is unable to replace the existing values in the table with the null values in Cassandra.

All the other values are getting updated except for the null values.

Comment: Can you please clarify which connector you're using? There are multiple Cassandra ones. Please show your config